# how to refer to image of sdcard for ImageAdapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have a list of images in my  drawable   folder   .
I have code to show them in coverflow.
So to refer images, I can use the following way  using  R.drawable.*_*     etc,  see below-

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private Context context;
    private ImageView[] images;
    private Integer[] imageids={
            R.drawable. image001,
            R.drawable. image002,
            R.drawable. image003,
            R.drawable. image004,
            R.drawable. image005,
            R.drawable. image006,

            R.drawable. image007,
            R.drawable. image008,
            R.drawable. image009,

            R.drawable. image011,

            R.drawable. image012,
            R.drawable. image013,
            R.drawable. image014,
            R.drawable. image015,
            R.drawable. image016,

            R.drawable. image017,
            R.drawable. image018,
            R.drawable. image019,
            R.drawable. image020,
            R.drawable. image021,
            R.drawable. image022,
            R.drawable. image023,
            R.drawable. image024,

        };
    public ImageAdapter(Context con)
    {
        this.context=con;
        images=new ImageView[imageids.length];
    }
}
```

**Now my question is how to refer the images of my SDCARD  in  above imageid   list.**
I have found a related question on stackoverflow but no answer.
Please anyone answer this question if know.
Can I create the list of  videoid's also in the same way????

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/mnt/sdcard/pathtoyourfile
```

can be used refer to the file in the sdcard. For example, if you have a image file as image.jpg in a folder named myfolder in sdcard you can have,

```
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/mnt/sdcard/myfolder/image.jpg");
imageView.setImageBitmap(b);
```

This path can be used for video as well. As I can see your array is type Integer.Instead you can use a String array.

BitmapFactory.decodeFile(""); is used to decode a file into a Bitmap. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile%28java.lang.String%29) you can find a documentation.

Comment: Hi Ambrish,
thanks. Please tell what is the use of  BitmapFactory.decodeFile   here??